# Why Does this ggplot with POSIXct dates give an Error in cut.default, cannot allocate vector

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I'm running a report, and have pulled out some data around something happening over time.  I have then summarised that data into a dataframe of date/times and counts.  When I try to plot it via ggplot2 I get an error

```
> ggplot(foo, aes(x=Date, y=Count))+
+       geom_line()
Error in cut.default(unclass(x), unclass(breaks), labels = labels, right = right,  : 
  cannot allocate vector of length 1317423601
> 
> ggplot(foo[2:349,], aes(x=Date, y=Count))+
+       geom_line()
Plot produced...
```

My data is using POSIXct dates, which do seem to cover the end of British Summer Time.  I also note that if I excldue the first row of data it works !.  Any ideas ?
Here's my data

```
> dput(foo)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1317423600, 1317445200, 1317466800, 
1317488400, 1317510000, 1317553200, 1317574800, 1317596400, 1317618000, 
1317639600, 1317661200, 1317682800, 1317704400, 1317726000, 1317747600, 
1317769200, 1317790800, 1317812400, 1317834000, 1317855600, 1317877200, 
1317898800, 1317920400, 1317942000, 1317963600, 1317985200, 1318006800, 
1318028400, 1318050000, 1318071600, 1318093200, 1318114800, 1318136400, 
1318158000, 1318179600, 1318201200, 1318222800, 1318244400, 1318266000, 
1318287600, 1318309200, 1318330800, 1318352400, 1318374000, 1318395600, 
1318417200, 1318438800, 1318460400, 1318503600, 1318525200, 1318546800, 
1318568400, 1318590000, 1318611600, 1318633200, 1318654800, 1318676400, 
1318698000, 1318719600, 1318762800, 1318784400, 1318806000, 1318827600, 
1318849200, 1318870800, 1318892400, 1318914000, 1318935600, 1318957200, 
1318978800, 1319000400, 1319022000, 1319043600, 1319065200, 1319086800, 
1319108400, 1319130000, 1319151600, 1319173200, 1319194800, 1319216400, 
1319238000, 1319259600, 1319281200, 1319302800, 1319324400, 1319346000, 
1319367600, 1319410800, 1319432400, 1319454000, 1319475600, 1319497200, 
1319518800, 1319540400, 1319562000, 1319583600, 1319605200, 1319626800, 
1319648400, 1319670000, 1319691600, 1319713200, 1319734800, 1319756400, 
1319778000, 1319799600, 1319821200, 1319842800, 1319864400, 1319886000, 
1319907600, 1319929200, 1319994000, 1320015600, 1320037200, 1320058800, 
1320080400, 1320102000, 1320123600, 1320145200, 1320166800, 1320188400, 
1320210000, 1320231600, 1320253200, 1320274800, 1320296400, 1320318000, 
1320339600, 1320361200, 1320382800, 1320404400, 1320426000, 1320447600, 
1320469200, 1320490800, 1320512400, 1320534000, 1320577200, 1320598800, 
1320620400, 1320642000, 1320663600, 1320685200, 1320706800, 1320750000, 
1320771600, 1320793200, 1320814800, 1320836400, 1320858000, 1320879600, 
1320901200, 1320922800, 1320944400, 1320966000, 1320987600, 1321009200, 
1321030800, 1321052400, 1321074000, 1321095600, 1321117200, 1321138800, 
1321182000, 1321203600, 1321225200, 1321246800, 1321268400, 1321290000, 
1321311600, 1321333200, 1321354800, 1321376400, 1321398000, 1321419600, 
1321441200, 1321462800, 1321484400, 1321506000, 1321527600, 1321549200, 
1321570800, 1321592400, 1321614000, 1321635600, 1321657200, 1321678800, 
1321700400, 1321722000, 1321743600, 1321765200, 1321786800, 1321808400, 
1321830000, 1321851600, 1321873200, 1321894800, 1321916400, 1321938000, 
1321959600, 1321981200, 1322002800, 1322024400, 1322046000, 1322067600, 
1322089200, 1322110800, 1322132400, 1322154000, 1322175600, 1322197200, 
1322218800, 1322240400, 1322262000, 1322305200, 1322326800, 1322370000, 
1322391600, 1322413200, 1322434800, 1322456400, 1322478000, 1322499600, 
1322521200, 1322542800, 1322564400, 1322586000, 1322607600, 1322629200, 
1322650800, 1322672400, 1322694000, 1322715600, 1322737200, 1322758800, 
1322780400, 1322802000, 1322823600, 1322845200, 1322866800, 1322888400, 
1322910000, 1322931600, 1322953200, 1322974800, 1322996400, 1323018000, 
1323039600, 1323061200, 1323082800, 1323104400, 1323126000, 1323147600, 
1323169200, 1323190800, 1323212400, 1323234000, 1323255600, 1323277200, 
1323298800, 1323320400, 1323342000, 1323363600, 1323385200, 1323406800, 
1323428400, 1323450000, 1323471600, 1323493200, 1323514800, 1323558000, 
1323579600, 1323601200, 1323622800, 1323644400, 1323666000, 1323687600, 
1323709200, 1323730800, 1323752400, 1323774000, 1323795600, 1323817200, 
1323838800, 1323860400, 1323882000, 1323903600, 1323925200, 1323946800, 
1323968400, 1323990000, 1324011600, 1324033200, 1324054800, 1324076400, 
1324098000, 1324119600, 1324141200, 1324162800, 1324206000, 1324227600, 
1324249200, 1324270800, 1324292400, 1324314000, 1324335600, 1324357200, 
1324378800, 1324400400, 1324422000, 1324443600, 1324465200, 1324486800, 
1324508400, 1324530000, 1324551600, 1324573200, 1324594800, 1324616400, 
1324638000, 1324659600, 1324681200, 1324702800, 1324724400, 1324767600, 
1324832400, 1324854000, 1324875600, 1324897200, 1324918800, 1324940400, 
1324962000, 1324983600, 1325005200, 1325026800, 1325048400, 1325070000, 
1325091600, 1325113200, 1325134800, 1325156400, 1325178000, 1325199600, 
1325221200, 1325242800, 1325264400, 1325286000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Count = c(3L, 0L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 
4L, 4L, 52L, 19L, 7L, 5L, 59L, 30L, 3L, 2L, 50L, 25L, 8L, 4L, 
41L, 22L, 4L, 8L, 57L, 12L, 14L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 
10L, 12L, 44L, 19L, 11L, 3L, 47L, 31L, 7L, 9L, 56L, 21L, 11L, 
54L, 20L, 10L, 6L, 54L, 17L, 0L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 14L, 
9L, 52L, 19L, 11L, 10L, 56L, 33L, 12L, 9L, 57L, 20L, 12L, 5L, 
51L, 23L, 14L, 5L, 50L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 
57L, 27L, 10L, 7L, 62L, 29L, 5L, 6L, 53L, 22L, 8L, 10L, 53L, 
12L, 7L, 9L, 38L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 81L, 27L, 
6L, 5L, 67L, 45L, 6L, 3L, 63L, 43L, 10L, 2L, 57L, 38L, 19L, 12L, 
54L, 22L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 53L, 44L, 7L, 
65L, 41L, 11L, 7L, 61L, 46L, 7L, 4L, 64L, 48L, 10L, 11L, 56L, 
39L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 46L, 45L, 16L, 6L, 
69L, 46L, 17L, 1L, 67L, 43L, 15L, 5L, 57L, 40L, 14L, 4L, 56L, 
36L, 3L, 0L, 11L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 59L, 45L, 9L, 7L, 
71L, 35L, 19L, 10L, 65L, 23L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
0L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 58L, 46L, 16L, 6L, 70L, 52L, 
14L, 8L, 84L, 42L, 10L, 6L, 62L, 44L, 11L, 3L, 58L, 28L, 3L, 
0L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 65L, 53L, 14L, 11L, 73L, 
42L, 14L, 8L, 74L, 33L, 15L, 13L, 75L, 53L, 11L, 10L, 61L, 31L, 
1L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 15L, 16L, 114L, 52L, 10L, 14L, 75L, 
50L, 14L, 9L, 69L, 52L, 12L, 15L, 77L, 35L, 10L, 5L, 69L, 37L, 
5L, 1L, 12L, 10L, 0L, 9L, 4L, 14L, 18L, 90L, 35L, 12L, 9L, 87L, 
49L, 10L, 22L, 83L, 41L, 15L, 14L, 79L, 48L, 17L, 6L, 40L, 8L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 54L, 31L, 11L, 6L, 
54L, 32L, 7L, 9L, 63L, 23L, 16L, 6L, 43L, 17L, 3L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Count"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 63L, 64L, 
65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 
91L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 
104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 
115L, 116L, 117L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 
128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 153L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 
163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 
175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 
186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 
197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 
208L, 209L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 
219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 227L, 228L, 230L, 231L, 
232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 
243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 
254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 
276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 
288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 
299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 
310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 
322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 
333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 341L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 
347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 
358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L), class = "data.frame")
```

and here's my original code

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x=Date, y=Count))+
        geom_line()
```

Comment: Kind of weird. Seems that cut.POSIXct would have been used. I get a different error but it's related to version mismatch and I'm sure you must be up-to-date.

Comment: Your first example runs for me (R 2.14.2 and ggplot 0.9.0). Hmmm...but it looks like @DWin also gets an error. Interesting.

Comment: My error `could not find function "initRefFields"` is already known to be due to my old version (2.14.0). Some people are just slow.

Comment: Like joran, both examples work for me. I'm running R 2.14.2 and ggplot2 0.9.0 on a Windows box.

Comment: So mine is R2.14.1 and ggplot2 something.  I'll try updating and retry.